# How to save a picture with a changing name to google drive in colab?

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I build a lot of pictures, and I need to save them all. I know how to save one image to google drive::

```
  #doing something
  
  fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
  # a picture is made
  plt.savefig("test.png")

  !gupload --to '1P_7-IJ3LmLmRK1wR8wclD8xRbVDzDhxZ' test.png
```

But if I create a picture in a for loop, is it possible to somehow save a picture every time with a new name, which will depend on k? (k is the variable through which the loop will go)

Comment: try `plt.savefig(f"test{k}.png")` or some variation

Comment: @sacuL thanks, it worked
Suddenly someone will need: 
to change the title of the image, you need to do this:
```plt.title("$k = $"+str(k), fontsize=30)```